# Want to add Different colors to Different Dynamic ids in a table

Tags: html, jquery

I am having some issues on `<tr>` background color, having the same `<tr id="">`
Here is my Table.

```
<table class="table">
<tr id="2552">
<td>Roll No 1</td>
<td>800</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2552">
<td>Roll No 1</td>
<td>700</td>
</tr>
<tr id="4444">
<td>Roll No 11</td>
<td>800</td>
</tr>
<tr id="4444">
<td>Roll No 11</td>
<td>900</td>
</tr>
<tr id="7676">
<td>Roll No 12</td>
<td>800</td>
</tr>
<tr id="7676">
<td>Roll No 12</td>
<td>900</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want. 
Every 2 `<tr>` have same `id` But these ids are dynamic. 
I want the `<tr>` having same `id` get different `background-color`. 
Now in this table there are `3 ids` are used. So 3 different colors can be there.

I have applied many jquery codes but failed. 
Please help me

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique in an HTML document, so this is not the right way to do this. How about storing this value in a `data` attribute instead?

Comment: yes we can do it <tr id=""> to <tr data="">
You have any solution?
i need just 2 colors. Grey and White. Toggle colors for every group of ids. Like all 2222 Will have background grey and next group of ids will show background white. then next  group of id show grey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Developed Dynamic table row id based color set and i hope its solve your problem. [Code Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/a2pq65hL/1/)

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var secondRow = table.rows[1];
var count=0;
var trid =[];
var clr =[];
for(var i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++)
{
trid.push(table.rows[i].id);
}
var uniqueArray = [];
for(i=0; i < trid.length; i++){
    if(uniqueArray.indexOf(trid[i]) === -1) {
        uniqueArray.push(trid[i]);
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < uniqueArray.length; i++)
{
    clr.push('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}


  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < uniqueArray.length; j++)
{
if(table.rows[i].id ==uniqueArray[j]){
  table.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = clr[j];
  }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You Are Awesome it worked perfectly. Now just one Question .
Can we fix the 2 colors only, Grey and White only. Your code works like a charm really. But I wish if I can fix just 2 colors. Right now it is using random colors many colors.

Comment: can you please do a little more help. I want to use only 2 colors. grey and white. How i can achieve this

Comment: But there are 3 different id here so how to set 2 color?

Comment: @muhammad Try my answer - it only produces two different colours, no matter how many ids you have

Comment: @Uday Dear I fixed it. I given two colors in clr=[] array. Repeated. 
Infact, sometimes. it gives too dark colors in background that my text don't appear. 
So i wished if we toggle only 2 color white and grey again white and grey. but I did it with clr array in your code.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sdo7we
Here you can see what i wanted and same i did with color array. Thank you so much. Your code worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use looping in Jquery, loop through each tr and determine its ID, then apply bg color

```
$( "tr" ).each(function( index ) {
  var ID = $(this)..attr('id');
  if(ID == '2221')
  {
     $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
  else  if(ID == '2223')
  {
     $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
  }

});
```

Comment: ID is not same every-time. Some time 8 digits, sometime 2 digits. Dynamically created IDs. Even i do not know which id will come for next record. But Records can be thousand or more.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
const used_ids = []
$( "tr" ).each(function( index ) {
    const id = $(this).attr.('id')
    if (!used_ids.includes(id)) {
        // If the id has not been met before, add it to the array.
        used_ids.push(id)
        }
    // Get index of id from array of used ids
    const index = used_ids.indexOf(id)

    // If index is an even number, set background colour to grey, otherwise white
    if (index%2 === 0) $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    else $(this).css('background-color', 'grey');
})
```

It builds an array of unique `id`s, then assigns white to those with an even index in the array and grey to the odd indices.